# Using PHP and oci8 to handle a query

Tags: php, oracle

This is a past paper question for a database class that I'm stuck with. I'm just preparing for my exam, so it's okay to give away the answer.

Consider the following schema:

```
Borrow(userid: string, callnum: string, copynum: integer, checkout: date, return: date)
```

Here is the PHP function that has an error.

```
function countCheckedOutBookCopies($callnum){

  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS bookcount FROM borrow

        WHERE return = null and callnum = '".$callnum."'";

  $stid = oci_parse($this->conn, $sql); //assume $this->con is correct

  if($row = oci_fetch_object($stid)){

    return $row->bookcount;

  } else{

    return -1;

  }

}
```

There are 3 questions.

1.Find the error and fix it.

2.Another error occurs, fix it.

3.Despite everything being fixed, the function would `return -1` all the time. Why is this?

I'm only familiar with procedural PHP using MySQL. But I tried running the code and was resulted with $stid returning boolean all the time because I don't know which part is right and which part is wrong.

Here are the things I've tried

1.Changing `'".$callnum."'` to just simply `'$callnum'` (because this is how I've always done it in MySQL)

2.Changing `return = null` to `return = 'null'` (but I don't think this is the case)

3.Maybe there is something wrong with the concept of getting `COUNT(*)` instead of just `*`

EDIT: Just a thought: I feel like oci8 and MySQL do pretty much the same thing, but is there a reason to prefer one over another? I'm sure MySQL is the more popular one, but my school seems to prefer using oci8 for exam questions

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the "Find the error" and "Another error occurs":

1.) "`return is null`",

2.) `this->conn` is probably supposed to be `this->con`,

3.) the code is missing `oci_execute($stid);`,

4.) `oci_free_statement($stid);`.

```
function countCheckedOutBookCopies($callnum){
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS bookcount FROM borrow
        WHERE return is null and callnum = '$callnum'";
  $stid = oci_parse($this->con, $sql); //assume $this->con is correct
  oci_execute($stid);

  $ret = -1;
  if($row = oci_fetch_object($stid)){
    $ret = $row->bookcount;
  }
  oci_free_statement($stid);
  return $ret;

}
```